# style.css loading but not rendering styles on page in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am seeing in my FireBug CSS window that style.css? version 4.7 is loading from

> localhost/bootstrap2wordpress/wp-content/themes/bootstrap2wordpress/

I used enqueuing instead of inline stylesheet link. Tried that too but it didn't work either. Problem is the styles from the style.css, main stylesheet are not being applied to my page. The nav bar item still has a list-style bullet and it is not the correct font or color.

Here's my enqueue code:

```
function bootstrap2wordpress_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap2wordpress-style', get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap2wordpress-navigation', get_template_directory_uri()
        .
        '/js/navigation.js', array(), '20151215', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap2wordpress-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri()
        .
        '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20151215', true);

    if (is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option('thread_comments'))
    {
        wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrap2wordpress_scripts');
```

Comment: Did you inspect to see if your rule is being overriden?

Answer (score 0):

To be sure that your style is not override by another rules, you can change the priority of the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action. That is in case where you have another styles loads with the same action.

The default value is 10. Higher number will be load after.

Don't forget that your js file, plugin can also modify CSS rules.

Some bootstrap shortcode plugin can create conflict with your rules. Look in the head of the render page to verify.

Hope this piece of answer helps you.